# realm mobile platform and denormalization

Tags: realm, denormalization

Realm Mobile Platform looks too good to be true!
https://realm.io
I'm a heavy NoSQL user, and I almost always find myself denormalizing data so you don't get situations like the following.

`group:
  members:
    - john:
         groups:
           -falcons:
             members:
               - steve:
                 groups:
...`

What I can't tell from Realm Mobile Platform is - does it resolve this sort of problem automatically?  If I have a user base of 10,000 user where everyone is is connected to everyone else via a chain of groups, will syncing a group result in downloading 10,000 user profiles as the group populates itself via adding users to members, groups to users, users to members ad infinitum?  If Realm avoids this sorta problem out of the box while still making everything theoretically accessible, I'm in!

Comment: What is up with the down vote with no explanation? I am asking if a particular piece of software has implemented a particular technology. Thanks in advance to the realm team for responding!

Comment: Well it wouldn't work too well if having a bidirectional many-many relation between two classes would somehow break synchronization. I don't know exactly how the sync works though, so I can't give a proper answer

Comment: Yeah, no idea how it works. A member of the realm team reached out to me to discuss the product, so I'm looking forward to reporting the answer back here asap.

Comment: Any luck with that?

Comment: Yup! Realm says that there is currently no partial replication in the server. So things need to be organized into separate realms to prevent massive downloads.